# Subdomínio não carrega estilos e scripts

Tags: asp.net-mvc, route, rotas, subdomínio, asp.net-mvc-routing

Bom dia,

1- Eu criei uma nova solução no Visual Studio 2012;

2- Eu criei ASP.NET MVC 4 Web Application. Optei por um projeto "BASIC", Framework 4.5 e a engine Razor;

3- Eu criei o controlador Home;

4- Eu criei a view Index.cshtml;

O conteúdo da página Index.cshtml tem apenas um texto e um debug

Eu não fiz nada, apenas o conteúdo principal de um projeto de "BASIC".

Publicado, ver o resultado:

O que devo fazer para que os scripts e estilos carregem no subdomínio?

Agradeço a ajuda.

Answer (score 1):

Este é o código fonte do subdomínio na data desta resposta. Repare que carregou scripts e css corretamente dentro de `<head>` na forma minificada:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
    <link href="/imobiliaria589s42d78/Content/css?v=ji3nO1pdg6VLv3CVUWntxgZNf1zRciWDbm4YfW-y0RI1" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <script src="/imobiliaria589s42d78/bundles/modernizr?v=qVODBytEBVVePTNtSFXgRX0NCEjh9U_Oj8ePaSiRcGg1"></script>

</head>
<body>


<h2>Host</h2>
<h2>imobiliaria589s42d78.meudominio.com.br</h2>


    <script src="/imobiliaria589s42d78/bundles/jquery?v=JzhfglzUfmVF2qo-weTo-kvXJ9AJvIRBLmu11PgpbVY1"></script>


</body>
</html>
<html>
<div id="haackroutedebugger" style="background-color: #fff; padding-bottom: 10px;">
    <style>
        #haackroutedebugger, #haackroutedebugger td, #haackroutedebugger th {background-color: #fff; font-family: verdana, helvetica, san-serif; font-size: small;}
        #haackroutedebugger tr.header td, #haackroutedebugger tr.header th {background-color: #ffc;}
    </style>
    <hr style="width: 100%; border: solid 1px #000; margin:0; padding:0;" />
    <h1 style="margin: 0; padding: 4px; border-bottom: solid 1px #bbb; padding-left: 10px; font-size: 1.2em; background-color: #ffc;">Route Debugger</h1>
    <div id="main" style="margin-top:0; padding: 0 10px;">
        <p style="font-size: .9em; padding-top:0">
            Type in a url in the address bar to see which defined routes match it. 
            A {*catchall} route is added to the list of routes automatically in 
            case none of your routes match.
        </p>
        <p style="font-size: .9em;">
            To generate URLs using routing, supply route values via the query string. example: <code>http://localhost:14230/?id=123</code>
        </p>
        <p><label style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 1.1em;">Matched Route</label>: {controller}/{action}/{id}</p>

        <div style="float: left;">
            <table border="1" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0" width="300">
                <caption style="font-weight: bold;">Route Data</caption>
                <tr class="header"><th>Key</th><th>Value</th></tr>
                    <tr><td>controller</td><td>Home&nbsp;</td></tr> <tr><td>action</td><td>Index&nbsp;</td></tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div style="float: left; margin-left: 10px;">
            <table border="1" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0" width="300">
                <caption style="font-weight: bold;">Data Tokens</caption>
                <tr class="header"><th>Key</th><th>Value</th></tr>

            </table>
        </div>
        <hr style="clear: both;" />
        <table border="1" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0">
            <caption style="font-weight: bold;">All Routes</caption>
            <tr class="header">
                <th>Matches Current Request</th>
                <th>Url</th>
                <th>Defaults</th>
                <th>Constraints</th>
                <th>DataTokens</th>
            </tr>
            <tr><td><span style="color: #c00">False</span></td><td>api/{controller}/{id}</td><td>id = </td><td>(empty)</td><td>(null)</td></tr><tr><td><span style="color: #c00">False</span></td><td>{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}</td><td>(null)</td><td>(empty)</td><td>(null)</td></tr><tr><td><span style="color: #0c0">True</span></td><td>{controller}/{action}/{id}</td><td>controller = Home, action = Index, id = UrlParameter.Optional</td><td>(empty)</td><td>(empty)</td></tr><tr><td><span style="color: #0c0">True</span></td><td></td><td>controller = Home, action = Index, id = </td><td>(empty)</td><td>(empty)</td></tr><tr><td><span style="color: #0c0">True</span></td><td>{*catchall}</td><td>(null)</td><td>(null)</td><td>(null)</td></tr>
        </table>
        <hr />
        <h3>Current Request Info</h3>
        <p>
            AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath is the portion of the request that Routing acts on.
        </p>
        <p><strong>AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath</strong>: ~/</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

**EDIT**

A rota está considerando inclusive os diretórios de bundling, o que é errado. Bundles são referências especiais do seu projeto.

Não sei como configura para a Locaweb, mas no seu caso o que resolve é fazendo a referência aos scripts e css estáticos (diretório `/Content/`) ou então usando CDN.

Conforme comentários, algo que pode resolver é especificar o seguinte no arquivo `web.config`:

```
<location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
```

Comment: Cigano, boa tarde. Primeiro obrigado pela ajuda. Então, no Chrome, se pressionar F12, e na aba NetWork, pressione F5 vc irá ver que não carrega os scripts (404
Not Found), já no domínio tudo carrega normal. Até mesmo se vc comparar o texto Host nas duas páginas vc percebe a diferença

Comment: Estou fazendo isso com uma aplicação em branco como essa, pois percebi que isso é o problema q está afetando minha aplicação.

Comment: @Lucas Onde você está hospedando sua aplicação? Você tem controle ao painel do IIS?

Comment: Então, está na locaweb, e não fiz nada. Veja:   http://wiki.locaweb.com/pt-br/Como_publico_uma_aplica%C3%A7%C3%A3o_usando_ASP.Net_MVC_%3F

Comment: @Lucas Editei a resposta.

Comment: Entendi, vou consideração sua explicação na locaweb, para tentar resolver. Quando eu faço referência estática direto sem usar bundles a página até fica certa, porém como minha aplicação tem o bootstrap e javascript, não valida os DataAnnotation. Na tela de login, clico no botão e nada acontece, não valida e não acessa o sistema.

Comment: Quanto a sua sugestão usar o CDN? Eu não conheço vou precisar ler sobre, mas adiantando usando o CDN na minha aplicação, tem bootstrap, validações DataAnnotations, a aplicação está separada em camadas BLL, DAL, MODEL.. tem AREAS, vai dar certo usando o CDN?

Comment: É que carregando as referências de outros sites tira esse problema de dentro da estrutura da Locaweb, e possivelmente resolve o problema.

Comment: Legal Cigano, não conhecia esse termo CDN, aprendi. Muito bem a noite vou testar, depois dou um feedback se deu certo. Obrigado, pela ajuda

Comment: Cigano, vc tem razão. Na hospedagem eles dizem para colocar <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false"> no web.config.

Comment: Porém agora, carrega os scripts e estilos, mas bati de frente com o seguinte problema:
 subdominio gera o seguinte form: 
<form method="post" action="/imobiliaria589s42d78/Admin/accountAdmin/login">  TRAZ PROBLEMA não acha o CONTROLLER

domínio gera:
<form method="post" action="/Admin/accountAdmin/login">    CORRETO e acessa o sistema normal e tudo funciona

Por favor, me ajude o que preciso fazer agora.
Obrigado.

Comment: @Lucas Agora é outro problema. Por favor, faça uma nova pergunta com seu novo problema.